# Why can’t I install/update an app from Play Store?

Tags: applications, lineageos

I use a Samsung S5 Neo, yes quite an old phone, but it works. Recently an app called „EBay Kleinanzeigen“ stopped working, so I wanted to update from the Play Store, which was not possible because it said „not compatible with your device“. At that time so ran the Samsung stock which was Android 6.

Now I updated to the latest Lineage OS which comes in version 17.1 based on Android 10. Everything worked fine, I reinstalled my apps, but EBay Kleinanzeigen still is shown as not compatible with device.

The app in question is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebay.kleinanzeigen and according Ronny understanding it should work from Android 5 to Android 11, hence what is wrong here?

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/marktplaats-b-v/ebay-kleinanzeigen-for-germany/ebay-kleinanzeigen-for-germany-13-6-0-release/ebay-kleinanzeigen-your-online-marketplace-13-6-0-2-android-apk-download/ reports:

Min: Android 5.0 (Lollipop, API 21)
Target: Android 11 (API 30)

Inhaber no idea, what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

Let us check what features/versions are required of that app:

I the `AndroidManifest.xml` is noted:

- `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"`

  - -> Minimum Android 5.0
- `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>`

  - -> requires OpenGL ES 2.0 (supported by Android 2.2) so it is a rather old version and should be supported by your device

There are more requirements but those are marked as "not required" (-> optional): camera, camera2, location, location.gps, telephony, wifi, touchscreen, screen.portrait, accelerometer.

In Play Store meta-data there is a dependency marked:

```
dependency:
    packageName: "com.google.android.gms"
    minVersionCode: 12451000 (the version code seems to belong the a version just released some days ago)
```

I am not sure if this is an optional or mandators dependency. So on a Google free device it may not work but as you have Play Store installed your device should have com.google.android.gms installed, not sure if the version is new enough.

Another potential restriction can be your selected Play Store country (the app seems to target Germany only). An app developer can also restrict to certain mobile network provider, but for this app such a restriction is unlikely.

**Finally according to Play Store this app is age restricted (age 16+)**, the chance is high that this is the problem. Have you set-up your birth date correctly in the used Google account?

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the hints. I checked all of them and my PlayStore country is set to Germany, as well as my age is well above 16 and configured accordingly. I contacted PlayStore support now and they forwarded me to the App developers, so let's see.

Comment: Now Google Play support forwarded me to the App provider, which I contacted today.